# Javascript - Add unique element id to multiple element with the same className

Tags: javascript

I have several elements with the className "error", I need to dynamically add a unique id to each one.  From other questions on stack I have put together the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function setErrorId() {
var errorClass = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
for (i = 0; i < errorClass.length; i++) {
    var idName = 'error' + i;
    errorClass[i].id = idName;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? (Also… why?)

Comment: That seems it should work fine, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: missing a closure `}`

Comment: `i` is an undefined variable

Comment: code seem right, you can check if errorClass get assignment with alert(errorClass). also "for (i;" normally should be "for (var i;"

Comment: So you were in strict mode and didn’t check errors? Setting undefined variables doesn’t usually cause an error in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an undefined variable `i`. just define it but other than that your fine.

```
function setErrorId () {
 var errorClass = document.getElementsByClassName('error')
   , i = 0
   , l = errorClass.length;

  while (i < l) {
    errorClass[i].id = 'error' + i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a }

like this:

```
function setErrorId() {
    var errorClass = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
    for (i = 0; i < errorClass.length; i++) {
    var idName = 'error' + i;
    errorClass[i].id = idName;
    }
}
```